# One data in Channel received by two routine

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Hello i learn about go routine and channel.
I do some experiment with channel, i send a data over channel and try to catch it in 2 functions. But my second function not run

Here is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func timeout(duration int, ch chan<- bool) {
    time.AfterFunc(time.Duration(duration)*time.Second, func() {
        ch <- true
    })
}

func watcher(duration int, ch <-chan bool) {
    <-ch
    fmt.Println("\nTimeout! no Answer after", duration, "seconds")
    os.Exit(0)
}

func watcher2(duration int, ch <-chan bool) {
    <-ch
    fmt.Println("This is watcher 2 as a second receiver")
}

func main() {
    var data = make(chan bool)
    var duration = 5

    go timeout(duration, data)
    go watcher(duration, data)
    go watcher2(duration, data)

    var input string
    fmt.Print("What is 725/25 ? ")
    fmt.Scan(&input)

    if input == "29" {
        fmt.Println("Correct")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Wrong!")
    }
}
```

Can you tell me some explanation about it?
Thank you

Comment: An item sent on a channel will only be received once.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andy Schweig mentioned, you can pull from Go channel only once. If you still want to receive message twice, you can use Observer design pattern:

```
import "fmt"

type Observer interface {
    Notify(message string)
}

type Watcher struct {
    name string
}

func (w Watcher) Notify(message string) {
    fmt.Printf("Watcher %s got message %s\n", w.name, message)
}

var watchers =  [...]Watcher {{name: "Watcher 1"}, {name: "Watcher 2"}}
var c = make(chan string)

func notifier() {

    var message string
    for {
        // Messaged pulled only once
        message = <- c

        // But all watchers still receive it
        for _, w := range watchers {
            w.Notify(message)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    go notifier()

    c <- "hello"
    c <- "how are you?"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `channel` you declared can only deal with one receiver. By default `channels` are `unbuffered`, meaning that they will only accept sends if there is a corresponding receiver to receive the sent value. Whereas a `buffered` channel accept a limited number of values without a corresponding receiver for those values.  If you are looking to inject multiple input and its subsequent receive then you need declare your `channel` as `buffered channel`.

```
ch := make(chan bool, n) //n being the number of items to buffer
```